# embedding content of Excel  in wicket framework

Tags: java, wicket

i want to embed generated excel on to my webpage. already i embed Pdf onto my webpage   but problem with my excel(.xls) file please help me.
      please tell me how to embed .xls file in my webpage.
          thanks a lot to help me all time i need help

Comment: I guess there's not a all-in-one solution for Wicket. You probably have to use a Java Excel reader and print the data out in a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never tried to do this, but you could:

1. As @rotsch already pointed out, use an Excel API such as [JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net) and roll your own grid. This wiki page might have some useful information: [How to work with Excel in Wicket using JExcel API](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/how-to-work-with-excel-in-wicket-using-jexcel-api.html)
2. If it is suitable to your needs, embed the file within an `<iframe>`. Notice that this might require the browser to be able to display the file (activeX controls, and similar). Here's a quick guide: [Displaying content (e.g. PDF, excel, word) in an IFRAME](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/displaying-content-eg-pdf-excel-word-in-an-iframe.html)